# Bar plot with multiple X-axis (category and Time) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bar plot with using the following sample data:

```
test  <- data.frame(person=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
                    value1=c(100,150,120,80,150),     
                    value2=c(25,30,45,30,30)) 

library(reshape2) # for melt

melted <- melt(test, "person")

melted$cat <- ''
melted[melted$variable == 'value1',]$cat <- "first"
melted[melted$variable == 'value2',]$cat <- "second"

melted$Date <- seq.Date(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-05-01"), "month")
```

And I am using the following code to create bar plot:

```
ggplot(melted, aes(x = cat, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

And it gives me the following output
[image]

However, I would like to create it month wise so that each month has two bars for value 1 and value 2. But when I do `x=Date`, it creates a stack plot (understandably),
[image]
however, I would like to create two bars for each  month.

Any guidance please?

Comment: Add `position = "dodge"` to your `geom_bar` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing `position = "dodge"`:

```r
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

# Make data
test  <- data.frame(person=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
                    value1=c(100,150,120,80,150),     
                    value2=c(25,30,45,30,30)) 

melted <- melt(test, "person")

melted$cat <- ''
melted[melted$variable == 'value1',]$cat <- "first"
melted[melted$variable == 'value2',]$cat <- "second"

melted$Date <- seq.Date(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-05-01"), "month")

# Plot
ggplot(melted, aes(x = Date, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer
Is it possible to create a stack bar plot meanwhile keeping ```position = dodge```?

Comment: I recommend searching on here since your previous question was already answered as well. If it hasn't been answered, then post a new question.